# Vscode Typescript Intellisense showing only first option?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript4.0

I'm working on my React Native (TypeScript) app and today, all of a sudden (*nothing updated*, *no settings changed*) my Intellisense started showing only first suggestion, no matter what:

[image]

This problem is not specific to a particular class, and I've restarted Vscode multiple times (restarted TS language server, deleted all Vscode caches from `~/Library/Caches/` (both `Code` folder and everything that starts with `com.microsoft` basically) but no avail.

How can I get rid of it? (Vscode Insiders 1.51.0 (which has been this same version for quite a few days of active use without the problem), TypeScript 4.0.5)

Answer (score 11):

Did you by any chance resize the widget while it was showing a single suggestion? Can you try "F1 > Reset Suggest Widget Size" and check if the widget size is back to normal?

Comment: in the future, suggestions like this that aren't asking the OP to try something, rather than proposing a definitive answer, should be a comment rather than answer.

Comment: This was an answer that solved the issue for me, so I'm glad it was posted as such so that it has better visibility for others.