# Visual Studio Code show intellisense one line?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, intellisense

[image: Image 1st picture]

Normally in Visual Studio Code program,  the "intellisense" would show a difference of options for a user to choose, based on the 1st picture. However, it only showed in one option in my program as the 2nd picture, which was an error. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it please? Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: press `Ctrl+Space` or `Ctrl+I`

Comment: I'm not sure what is the actual issue. If you are talking about the vertical lines it's by default, it connects the open and close of parenthesis and braces, which is very useful to identify the scope if you are in a large file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633862/vscode-typescript-intellisense-showing-only-first-option/64892000#64892000 or try dragging the bottom border of the suggestion widget down to expand it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. When I floated over the bottom edge of the single-line intellisense block it gave me a double arrow. From there I could drag the box to the size I want. Not sure how it became single-line, but that worked for me.